# Are stickers with Holograms called anything in particular?

Tags: print-design, print-production

I'm not even sure if i'm searching for the right term. is hologram sticker how this material is called?

[image]

Comment: This isn't a question that fits within the scope of SE and is a likely candiate for spam.  While I wish you the best in finding a company this question was closed due to answers that would likely change over time.

Comment: At this time I've removed the portion requesting manufactures.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## "Anti-Counterfit HOLOGRAM Stickers"

[image]

I found there is a big difference between 
**hologram (3D)** and **holographic (shiny)** stickers!

## Disclaimer: I've never tried any of these services.

I believe you would then print the 2 colors (white underneath blue) over these holograms, I'm not sure what type of ink or what press handles that.

[image]

intel specifically prints their image over a hologram. I scratched one so you can see.

There are a lot of generic names to call this type of sticker.

> "Security Hologram Stickers & Labels Custom Hologram
>   Design, Premium Quality Anti-countefeit, anti-tamper protection for
>   your products, documents, ID badges."
>
> Different types of anti-tamper include
>
> - 2D/3D parallax
> - Dot-matrix
> - Flip-flop
> - True Color
> - True 3D

I've never used this service before but now you have something to start your personal research in the field of "Anti-Countefit Holographic Stickers"

[image]

---

I've been advised to remove my sources. Google searching the terms I've provided should provide you with some companies. It's going to be very expensive < $1,000 and nobody is going to do a limited run for you because you have to print ink over a hologram. Probably a minimum of 5000 stickers at least maybe more.

Comment: These kind of anti counterfeit stickers tend to be ALL holographic foil rather than part foil as described in the original question.

Comment: @Westside I'm not an expert on holographic stickers specifically but I'm pretty sure you just print over the holographic part. I've had to setup artwork before that was going to be printed over holographic foil. I'm pretty sure this is the same thing.

Comment: @Westside edit: I added that information.

Comment: It’s possible to print on a foil substrate, maybe with a white screen print to back up the colour for opacity, but the effect in the Intel stickers is more likely foil applied to a specific area of a sticker printed on a white substrate. I’d have to find one and attack it with my fingernail or a blade to be sure though.

Comment: @Westside I just scratched an intel sticker. I felt bad doing it. Anyway it looks like 2 colors printed over hologram foil!

Comment: Please be careful when answering questions that ask for a service as those companies you reference will change over time and you will likely receive downvotes regarding the possibility others think you're spamming, though that may not be your intended purpose.  I would suggest editing your question to remove the companies and leave the portion that helps define what a hologram image is.

Comment: @DᴀʀᴛʜVᴀᴅᴇʀ Okay I did what you said I hope that helps. I'm always open to more suggestions.

Answer (score 2):

It’s holographic foil and it is applied in the same way as any another metallic foil. Sometimes this is done as a separate process after the printing, but some specialist label printers can apply the foil in line with the other print processes.

The exact pattern of the hologram will depend on what the printer can source, but anybody that can produce such labels should be able to provide you with samples. The Intel one is probably bespoke and exclusive.

One last point: it’s pretty expensive.

Comment: I can't seem to google "bespoke" can you confirm that with a source?

Comment: Bespoke is just an English word the means it’s specially made for that purpose for that customer.

Comment: "Custom made", in other words "rather expensive".

Comment: @usr2564301 One of those words that instantly tells you what side of the world I'm from.